# how to set the dynamic height width of child containers in paent container

Tags: flutter, dart

Auto expanding Container in flutter -- for all devices

```dart
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius:
          BorderRadius.circular(10),
      border:
          Border.all(color: lightBgColor),
    ),
    height: daysList[index].isEmpty ?  50 : null,
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Wrap(
      children: [
        ...daysList[index].map((e) =>
            Container(
              height: 40,
              margin:
                  const EdgeInsets.all(4),
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: lightBgColor,
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.circular(
                        10),
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment:
                    MainAxisAlignment
                        .spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment:
                    CrossAxisAlignment
                        .center,
                mainAxisSize:
                    MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text(e.name),
                  IconButton(
                    constraints:
                        const BoxConstraints(),
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets
                            .symmetric(horizontal: 4),
                    splashRadius: 8,
                    onPressed: () => removeExercise(e, index),
                    icon: const Icon(
                      size : 22,
                      Icons.delete,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ))
      ],
    )),
```

I tried this and it works , So I wanted to share this

Comment: It looks like you're trying to share knowledge, but in its current format it's unlikely that many people will find this. Did you see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer, on how to properly post a question and self-answer (once you have enough reputation)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto expanding Container in flutter -- for all devices

```dart
Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius:
          BorderRadius.circular(10),
      border:
          Border.all(color: lightBgColor),
    ),
    height: daysList[index].isEmpty ?  50 : null,
    width: double.infinity,
    child: Wrap(
      children: [
        ...daysList[index].map((e) =>
            Container(
              height: 40,
              margin:
                  const EdgeInsets.all(4),
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: lightBgColor,
                borderRadius:
                    BorderRadius.circular(
                        10),
              ),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment:
                    MainAxisAlignment
                        .spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment:
                    CrossAxisAlignment
                        .center,
                mainAxisSize:
                    MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text(e.name),
                  IconButton(
                    constraints:
                        const BoxConstraints(),
                    padding:
                        const EdgeInsets
                            .symmetric(horizontal: 4),
                    splashRadius: 8,
                    onPressed: () => removeExercise(e, index),
                    icon: const Icon(
                      size : 22,
                      Icons.delete,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ))
      ],
    )),
```

I tried this and it works , So I wanted to share this